# Installing applications OTA

Tags: blackberry, installation

I have a system set up to download jad files on users' Blackberries, but it only works intermittently, and seemingly randomly.  If the user clicks on the link within their BlackBerry browser, 95% of the time on the first try an error message will pop up saying there was an HTTP 500 error (which our server never returns).

Viewing the details of this message within the blackberry browser, it says nothing but `java.lang.nullpointerexception` which, again, could not have come from our server (running apache/php).

However, if the user clicks on the link a few more times, or navigates away and goes back to that page, it suddenly works.  No change on the server, it just shows the application install screen.  Unfortunately, this doesn't always work; sometimes the error 500 just keeps showing up.

The link is rather long (containing an sha hash as a token as part of the URL), but I would think that a long URL would either *always* be broken or *always* work, not work intermittently.

The link uses a php script to download the jad and cod files.  Linking to the files directly rather than using the script seems to work more often (I haven't determined if that also ever has an error 500 or not), but I can't find any issues with the headers.  The content type is set correctly and, like I said, if the headers were an issue, I'd think it would either *always* work or *always* break.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to shed some light on the problem by looking at the event logs, which you can get using JavaLoader:

**javaloader -u eventlog > event.log**

Search for NullPointerException within those logs and you'll be able to see what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain the intermittent behaviour, but I had a similar situation where I was getting the `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the browser details. Unfortunately, the Event Log (as dumped by `javaloader.exe`) or by viewing on-device using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> didn't show the exception.

(I'm using `bb-ant-tools` and JDE 4.6.1.) When the signature tool ran, I noticed that there were *two* `.cod` files being signed and I can see both of them inside the `.jar` file the compiler creates. But the output written was a single `.cod` file of size 92306 bytes that was *not* a .zip of smaller `.cod` files. The compiler somehow was not able to create a `.cod` that contained siblings. For comparison, compiling the project with JDE 5.0.0 created sibling `.cod` files that were able to be loaded over OTA.

My project included an `.mp3` file of 53542 bytes which I happened to not require. After removing it, the 4.6.1 compiler outputted a single `.cod` and I was able to successfully download it via OTA.